# Image path have special characters when it's bind to gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to bind images to grid-view from path stored in database.

lets say path stored in database is 
`../Images/Products/ScentTower.png`

when the image bind to grid view the path appears this format

```
`../Images/Products/ScentTower%0d.png`
```

what is causing that?

```
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Image ID="imageControl"  runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Picture") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%0d` is the carriage return character (`\n`). There is a line break in your file name. I don't know any operating system that allows this, so the best thing to do is make sure you have proper input validation and checks in the database that prevents unwanted characters in your file name.

One way to validate the file name is to check on `Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()`. If you don't want to do input validation, you can normalize the image URL by removing or replacing all occurrences from any character in that list.

Answer (score 2):

What about making sure special characters don't get in to your folders / database to begin with?

Comment: theirs no special characters added in database it only added when it bind to gridview

Answer (score 1):

"%0d" means '\n'.

Therefore your path stored in database appears like

```
../Images/Products/ScentTower
    .png
```

instead of

```
 ../Images/Products/ScentTower.png
```

try to remove any whitespace in column path.